# In CloudWatch Insights, how do I build a histogram of an aggregation function (second level query)?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm not sure I'm asking this correctly which is probably why I can't find the solution. So I'll provide an example.

Suppose I have a log of employees hired by managers in a given time period. I can create a query that groups by manager and shows the number of employees hired

```
stats count() as numEmployees by managerId
| filter @message like /hired employee/
| sort numEmployees desc
```

Let's suppose that generates the following table

```
Mngr | numHires
Jack | 4
Judy | 3
May  | 3
John | 2
Jake | 2
Mary | 1
Sam  | 1
Alan | 1
```

I'd like to further refine my result so that I can produce another histogram of numHires and count like so

```
4 | 1
3 | 2
2 | 2
1 | 3
```

This table means there was 1 instance of 4 hires, 2 instances of 3 hires, 2 instances of 2 hires, and 3 instances of 1 hire.

Is there a way to do this?

ps - I know I can download the csv and do this in excel. However, there is a `limit` of 10000 results returned in cloudwatch

Comment: subquery at cloudwatch insights is not possible, i tried several but aliasing the query(making it sub) and then querying it outside doesn't look possible.

Comment: Insights [just added support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-stats-query-command/) for two layers of `stats` — i.e. second-level aggregation capability!  

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same type of aggregation and raise a support case with AWS to ask how this could be done. The response from the AWS team was that unfortunately at the moment it is not possible using Insights.

> Insights does not have the capabilities for second level aggregations
> currently.
>
> So an alternate workaround is to use AWS Quick Sights or MS Excel to
> plot the required graphs.

In my case Excel is not an option because my the resulting dataset for a day has millions of records. That being said in the end my solution was to sample over just a few minutes of data, export this to Excel, and generate a pivot table to aggregate the data. This allowed me to get a rough idea of my system.

I have not looked into AWS Quick Sights.

There may be other third-party solutions besides AWS Insights, such as Datadog, that provide more powerful log analysis functionality. I have not used Datadog personally so cannot vouch for it but have read good things about it.

References:
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/histogram-charts.html

Comment: Insights [just added support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-stats-query-command/) for two layers of `stats` — i.e. second-level aggregation capability!  